# List Item is not clickable in Android

Tags: android, listview, onclick, android-event

I have a Custom ListView, in the List there is 3 ImageView and 4 Textview . I can not tap on the List Items and I am able to tap on the blank spcae. So what to do to tap on the List item and the onClick Listener should work ?

Comment: Do you have a custom adapter as well?

Comment: put this in your code and see what it does...: 
    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
     Log.i(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), " ->"
      + Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[2].getMethodName());

    } Does it debug when you tap on a list item?

Comment: why don't you post code so we can see what you are potentially doing wrong?

Comment: @Th0rndike yes using custom adapter

Answer (score 3):

If there are clickable views in your list cells, you must set these wiews not focusable (in code, after setting your onClickListeners) for the cell to be clickable as well by calling :

```
myCellButton.setOnClickListener(buttonClickListener);
myCellButton.setFocusable(false);
```